# Does Sorcerous Blade Channeling allow to use Acid Orb or Dragonfrost as basic melee attack

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer

Sorcerer's Acid Orb and Dragonfrost has the following special text (PHB2, p.138-139):

> **Special:** This power can be used as a ranged basic attack.

Sorcerous Blade Channeling benefit is (PHB2, p. 189):

> **Benefit:** When you use any ranged sorcerer attack power through a dagger, you can use the power as a melee attack. If you do so, the power's range equals your melee range.

Does this enable using the Acid Orb and the Dragonfrost powers as basic melee attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because the special merely says they are *ranged* basic attacks, and the Blade Channeling feat doesn't say anything about changing that. You'll end with up with a ranged basic attack that can be used as an ordinary melee atttack as well.

Comment: Aw, man. Need to try convincing GM to allow it with a house rule.